# How to `awk` print a space-separated field which contains space characters?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, awk, whitespace

I am trying to print the list of all files and folders including hidden files:

```
ls -al | awk -F' ' '{print $9}' | xargs do_something
```

However, some of the files and/or folders contain space characters. How could I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for starters.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf "%p\n"|xargs -i sh -c 'echo found: "{}"'
found: ./file2
found: ./folder 2
found: ./folder
found: ./file 1
found: ./ file 3

$ ls |awk '{print}'|xargs -i sh -c 'echo found "{}"'
found: file2
found: folder 2
found: folder
found: file 1

$ ls |xargs -i sh -c 'echo found "{}"'
found: file2
found: folder 2
found: folder
found: file 1
```

`ls -A` to list hidden files/folders too and exclude `.` and `..`

Using while loop for your backup

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="/home"

while IFS= read -r line; do 
    fullpath="$line"
    dirname=$(dirname "$line")
    basename=$(basename "$line")
    echo "$fullpath, $dirname, $basename"
    

    # your code
    # ...
done < <( 
    find "${DIR}" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf "%T@ %p\n"| # print files/folders with TSP 
    sort -n|  # sort timestamp (maybe sort -nr)
    awk '{sub(/[^ ]+ /,"")}1' # remove first field (TSP)
)
```

Comment: This works but the `xargs do_something` after `awk` still takes the space-separated field as 2 different strings.

Comment: as you can see in my example "`file 1`" & "`folder 2`" are space separated.

Comment: No, your original answer works. Don't need the extra `\"` and `\"`. Please update your answer.

Comment: i used double quotes to show you it was just one string!..

Comment: btw,, you don't need `awk` part only if you want modify output

Comment: I want to use `du` to check the sizes of various artefacts on my `/home` folder to exclude from scheduled backup.

Comment: How to enhance your script so that the artefacts are time ordered (both increment and decrement)?

Comment: No, `ls` does NOT list the hidden files / folders!

Comment: `ls -A` to list hidden files/folders excluding `.` and `..`

Comment: I can use `ls -At | |xargs -i sh -c 'echo found "{}"'` to order timestamp. How to achieve it with `find`?

Comment: try this `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf "%T@ %P\n"|sort -n|awk '{$1="";print}' |xargs -i sh -c 'echo found: "{}"'`

Comment: Look at the while loop example!

Comment: What does `awk '{$1=""; sub(/^ /,"")}1` do?

Comment: Isn't `$1=""` sufficient to remove the timestamp?

Comment: `$1=""`  makes the first field empty and produces a whitespace in your output.. therefore the sub

Comment: But `awk '{$1="";print}'` worked?

Comment: create a file with space at the begining. test it with `%P` and  `%p`.. better you use `%p` lowercase to avoid such cases

Comment: `%P     File's name with the name of the starting-point under which it was found removed.` - very confusing language. Why do you switch to `%p` when `%P` is sufficient?

Comment: no it isn't.  coz if u have `[ ]*filex` and `filex` you gonna get filex twice without any white spaces at the begining!..

Comment: maybe you don't have such cases and `%P` is ok for you

Comment: In that case, how would the `ls -At` variant look like? Would it still work?

Comment: you can use `xargs ... -d '\n' ...`

Comment: Using `%p` produce different results. All the files show up with `./` prefix.

Comment: are you using the while loop or xargs?

Comment: I am using `xargs`.

Comment: `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf "%T@ %p\n"|sort -nr|awk '{$1="";print}' |xargs -i sh -c 'F=$(basename "{}"); echo found: "$F"'`    $F is the basename

Comment: `awk '{$1="";print}'` will convert all chains of blanks and/or tabs in the file names to single blank chars, thereby corrupting them, and will leave a leading blank which further messes up the output. Just do `awk '{sub(/[^ ]+ /,"")}1'` or even `cut -d' ' -f2-` instead to remove the timestamp.

Comment: Actually, use a tab in the find output so you can just use the default cut separator: `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf "%T@\t%p\n"|sort -nr| cut -f2-|...`